# Uncheck checkbox if clicked on that corresponding div

Tags: jquery

I have set of checkboxes on the left panel, when i click any one checkbox i activate a div filter on right top pane which contains  a cross, when i click that cross the checkbox should get unchecked this should happen dynamically for checkboxes.

This is my progress:

https://jsfiddle.net/edaatzy8/1/

I tried this code but does not seem to work:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for unchecking the corresponding checkbox:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).attr('checked', false);
});
```